Where are the tags defined at the dataset level using .log_input in mlflow?
I want to tag the dataset within the run in mlflow. I have tried .log_input and it works to store the metadata of the dataset. However, the tags are not shown in the ui. And cannot be accessed either.
Where are the tags defined at the dataset level? If not in ui then where are they present??
